# How can I specify message encoding for incoming messages in a WCF client based on the message encoding in the response message from the server?

Tags: encoding, message, wcf-client, mtom

How can I specify message encoding for incoming messages in a WCF client based on the message encoding in the response message from the server?

The server can send the response with text message encoding or MTOM?

How can it be determined and accordingly how can I specify message encoding at the client, after a response is received from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the message encoding, you need to define a binding configuration - pick whichever binding you're using, and define that you want e.g. MTOM encoding:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MTOM" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Then, in your endpoints both on the server and the client (they must line up and define the same thing!), you need to use that binding configuration:

```
  <service name="test" >
    <endpoint name="test"
        address=""
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="MTOM"
        contract="IYourService" />
  </service>
```

You have to set this up both on the client and the server - you need to decide ahead of time, whether or not to use MTOM encoding (instead of regular text encoding).

Comment: Thank you, but I have a different query. Can I know the encoding of a response from server before the message is actually decoded and so that I can use a proper endpoint with the same encoding on client side as used for the response at the server end.

Comment: @klra: I tried to explain that: **no** you cannot do this - you need to decide **ahead of time** when you configure the services what encodings will be used on what endpoints. You cannot "magically" detect that for each message - it has to be decided and configured.

Comment: OK, can we atleast determine the message encoding of an incoming message at any level at client side or at server side?

Comment: @klra: no - but why would you need to?? You must have a static configuration, so if you call your server on any given endpoint, you know from configuration what encoding it will have....

Comment: This is required because the server can send the text encoded or MTOM encoded message. However, some people write that the endpoint configured with MTOM encoding can accept string encoded message as well and will be deserialized properly, but I am  not sure.